# How to present a View Controller from the Detail View Controller correctly?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a `UISplitViewController` which presents a `UIViewController` with the following code:

```
self.splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden;
UIViewController *quiz = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self showDetailViewController:quiz sender:self];
```

I want to be able to present more view controllers from the already presented detail view controller that has been presented with `-showDetailViewController`. Do I simply call `-presentViewController:animated:completion:` or am I able to replace the current detail view controller with the view controller I would like to present?

The problem that I am have is that my `quiz` vc has a button with the following code that brings the user back to the UISplitViewController. When I use this code from the vc that the `quiz` vc presented with `-presentViewController:animated:completion:` nothing happens, but if this code is executed directly from the `quiz` vc it takes the user back to the main split view controller.

```
self.splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible;
UIViewController *mainDetailVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]
                                  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainDetailVC"];
[self.splitViewController showDetailViewController:mainDetailVC sender:self];
```